# I am uploading files to google drive subfolder but it's uploading files only to the root directory

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

here is my code in controller

constructor code in

```
 private $drive;
        public function __construct(\Google_Client $client)
        {
            $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) use ($client) {
                $accessToken = [
                    'access_token' => auth()->user()->token,
                    'created' => auth()->user()->created_at->timestamp,
                    'expires_in' => auth()->user()->expires_in,
                    'refresh_token' => auth()->user()->refresh_token
                ];
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
                if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                    if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
                        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                    }
                    Auth::user()->update([
                        'token' => $client->getAccessToken()['access_token'],
                        'expires_in' => $client->getAccessToken()['expires_in'],
                        'created_at' => $client->getAccessToken()['created'],
                    ]);
                }
                $client->refreshToken(auth()->user()->refresh_token);
                $this->drive = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
                return $next($request);
            });
        }
```

the method that uploading files to drive I think the problem is this method

```
   function createFile($file, $parent_id = null){ 
        $fileName = FileStorage::find($file)->first();
                $name = pathinfo(asset('uploadedfiles/' . $fileName->filenames));
                $meta = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
                    'name' => $name['basename'],
                    'parent' => '1GJ3KC-vsBrLAtlwUYgOvm7AjrtIXb4t-',// Parent Folder ID
                ]);
                $content = File::get('uploadedfiles/' . $fileName->UniqueFileName);
                $mime = File::mimeType('uploadedfiles/' . $fileName->UniqueFileName);
                $file = $this->drive->files->create($meta, [
                    'data' => $content,
                    'mimeType' => $mime,
                    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
                    'fields' => 'id',
                ]);
        }
```

where is the problem in my code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the definition of `$this->drive`? That way it should be easier to follow https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/folder#php

Comment: @Techno you can see the whole controller code now

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason your code does not look like the code on https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/folder#php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is going to root is that you are not setting a parent folder.
You are using the parameter `parent` when in fact the parameter you should be using is `parents` and the value should be an array.  parent is just getting ignore since its not a valid parameter

[image]

## change

```
$meta = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
                'name' => $name['basename'],
                'parent' => '1GJ3KC-vsBrLAtlwUYgOvm7AjrtIXb4t-',// Parent Folder ID
            ]);
```

## to

```
$meta  = new Drive\DriveFile(array(
        'name' => $name['basename'],
        'parents' => array('1GJ3KC-vsBrLAtlwUYgOvm7AjrtIXb4t-')
    ));
```

Comment: Images of text are not useful for users with visual impairments, or users with imgur blocked at work. Just copy and paste the test please!

Comment: I will add you a link tomorrow.